# ITextSharp insert existing table into pdf document

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, basic

I have been using ITextSharp to replicate the information on a webpage so that the information on the page can be printed in PDF format.

I generate my table by using the following code.

```
Protected Sub GenerateTable(noOfRows As Integer, reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader)
    Dim table As Table
    Dim row As TableRow
    Dim cell As TableCell
    Dim lbl As Label
    Dim lblVolume As Label
    Dim lblUnitPrice As Label
    Dim lblTotalPrice As Label
    table = VolumeTable
    table.ID = "VolumeTable"

    'Page.Form.Controls.Add(table)
    For i As Integer = 1 To noOfRows Step 1
        row = New TableRow()

        For j As Integer = 0 To 5 Step 1
            cell = New TableCell()
            If j = 1 Then
                lblVolume = New Label()
                lblVolume.ID = "LabelRow_" & i & "Col_" & j
                cell.Controls.Add(lblVolume)
                lblVolume.Text = reader.GetValue(2)
            ElseIf j = 2 Then
                lblUnitPrice = New Label()
                lblUnitPrice.ID = "UnitLabel" & i
                lblUnitPrice.Text = "Unit Price: "
                cell.Controls.Add(lblUnitPrice)
            ElseIf j = 3 Then
                lblUnitPrice = New Label()
                lblUnitPrice.ID = "LabelRow_" & i & "Col_" & j
                cell.Controls.Add(lblUnitPrice)
                lblUnitPrice.Text = reader.GetValue(5)
            ElseIf j = 4 Then
                lblUnitPrice = New Label()
                lblUnitPrice.ID = "TotalPrice" & i
                lblUnitPrice.Text = "Total Price: "
                cell.Controls.Add(lblUnitPrice)
            ElseIf j = 5 Then
                lblTotalPrice = New Label()
                lblTotalPrice.ID = "LabelRow_" & i & "Col_" & j
                cell.Controls.Add(lblTotalPrice)
                lblTotalPrice.Text = reader.GetValue(6)
            ElseIf j = 0 Then
                lbl = New Label()
                lbl.ID = "Label" & i
                lbl.Text = "Volume " & i
                cell.Controls.Add(lbl)
            End If


            row.Cells.Add(cell)
        Next
        table.Rows.Add(row)
        reader.Read()
    Next

    'SetPreviousTableData(noOfRows)
    ViewState("RowsCount") = noOfRows
    Session("RowsCount") = noOfRows

End Sub
```

How would I go about replicating this table in ITextSharp using Visual Basic. All of the solutions I have looked at so far have been in C# but I cant figure out to do this in VB

any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the most basic usage of iTextSharp in VB.Net. I'm not binding it to any data model, just two loops for rows and columns since it seems like you've got that part down. See the code comments for more details.

```
''//Filename that we're going to write to
Dim FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test.pdf")

''//Create a Stream to write to. This could also be a MemoryStream or anything else that inherits from System.IO.Stream
Using FS As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)

    ''//Create an abstract PDF document
    Using Doc As New Document()

        ''//Create a PdfWriter that binds the abstraction to the stream
        Using Writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, FS)

            ''//Open the document to allow writing
            Doc.Open()

            ''//Create a Pdf table with 4 columns
            Dim table As New PdfPTable(4)

            ''//Loop through 10 rows
            For RowNumber = 1 To 10

                ''//Loop through 4 columns
                For ColumnNumber = 1 To 4

                    ''//Write some text to the table
                    table.AddCell(New Paragraph(String.Format("Hello from {0}x{1}", RowNumber, ColumnNumber)))

                Next

            Next

            ''//Add the table to the document
            Doc.Add(table)

            ''//Close the document to disable writing and flush buffers
            Doc.Close()

        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```